# how to pass arguments in QAndroidjniobject?

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, android-wifi

I am trying to add android code to qt project.
this is my .java code

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

static  String ssid;

@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
     if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {
       // Do your work.

       // e.g. To check the Network Name or other info:
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
       ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
       getinfo();
     }
  }
 public static String getinfo()
 {
     return ssid;
 }
}
```

my cpp code is

```
void WIFICLASS::updateAndroidNotification()
{

qDebug()<<"******************************************8";
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/example/WifiReceiver","onReceive","(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V;",QtAndroid::androidContext().object());

    QAndroidJniObject returnString = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/example/WifiReceiver","getinfo","()Ljava/lang/String;");


      QString user = returnString.toString();


     qDebug()<<"answer"<<user;

    }
```

What argument I should use for `(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V;",QtAndroid::androidContext().object());` as in my java code I am using void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) **intent** as argument..